# Angular $rootScope object property not accessible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

My `$rootScope.globals` object is below:

```
{
 currentUser: {
    id: "56309272279724c02b319392"
    name: "Özgür Adem"
    picture: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c4ca4238a0b23452sdcc503a6f76829z?  d=retro"
    ptoken: "mFFa9l25HbB4fbh7"
    role: Object
 },
 unread: 0
}
```

When I print to console like this `console.log($rootScope.globals)` or `console.log($rootScope.globals.currentUser)` everything good.

But when I try print `console.log($rootScope.globals.unread)`, output being `undefined`.

Why? I think if property value equal to `undefined`, it shouldn't seen as 0 in other outputs. Am I wrong?

What's wrong here?

Comment: I dnt find any problem. it should work

Comment: @Sajeetharan I think so but not working

Comment: @Furkan, do you see the value as o for `unread` when printing `console.log($rootScope.globals)`

Comment: Try using Batarang, that would be really helpful in these cases.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: @M22an yes when i printing `console.log($rootScope.globals)` I can see unread's value but when i try `console.log($rootScope.globals.unread)` I got `undefined`.

Comment: Are you trying both console.log in the same controller ?

Comment: Yes I try this in the same controller

Comment: Then unless the `$rootScope.globals` was modified in between these two `console.log()` requests, there is no reason for this error to happen.

Comment: Where's the code that generates this issue? A demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates the problem would also help. Nobody can do much to help you with what little is provided in your question

Comment: Obviously the reason is to be found in the information you don't gave us. A wild guess: `undefined` is a strong indication that the property doesn't exist. Maybe there's a typo and `globals` actually has a property named `unred`, for instance, or the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any problem with your code, may be you have not injected $rootScope but here is the working [`Plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/zOEQtSlU5flDzmK35p2U?p=preview)

**Controller code:**

```
App.controller('TodoController',['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope){

   $rootScope.globals = {
 currentUser: {
    id: "56309272279724c02b319392",
    name: "Özgür Adem",
    picture: "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c4ca4238a0b23452sdcc503a6f76829z?  d=retro",
    ptoken: "mFFa9l25HbB4fbh7",
    role: Object
 },
 unread: 0
}
   console.log($rootScope.globals.unread) 
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I didn't injected $rootScope, how can I access other property in $rootScope object? :)

Comment: other property means? what do you want to access, just fork the plunker code and change the variables as you require

Comment: in the sample i provided am printing unread and it shows as 0